# Socket.io MVC node.js emit to room

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have been looking into this [Socket.io MVC node.js](https://github.com/misirlu13/Socket.MVC) but I'm currently struggling.

It says in the documentation:

> Socket.io API's
>
> Since Socket.MVC is just a wrapping mechanism for Socket.io, all of
>   the same API's can be used using the Socket.MVC module. Please see a
>   list of all of the API's available by visiting the Socket.io Github
>   page, or http://socket.io (depending on your version)

My problem is that I cant find a way to emit socket MVC to a room.

```
socketMVC.to(userid).emit('message', {message:2});
```

Should work, but it doesn't. Any idea how I can accomplish this?

EDIT:
userid is same as assigned here:
import  * as io from 'socket.io-client';

download

```
oninit:
      this.socket = io(this.socketurl);


      var privateRoom = socket.request.session.passport.user;

        socket.join(privateRoom);


      this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
            //  this.messagesCounter = this.messagesCounter + 1;
              alert("OMG?");
          });
```

edit , in server.js

```
io.on('connection',function(socket) {
    console.log('user connected');
    OnlineUsers.push(socket);
  //  socket.join('');
    console.log(socket.request.session.passport);
    console.log("user is connceted");




    socketMVC.init(io, socket, {
        debug: true,
        filePath: ['./src/routes/sockets.js']
    });



socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
});

socket.on('add-message',function (message) {
    io.emit('message', {type:'new-message', text: message});
});

    socket.on('myevent', function(someData) {
        console.log("MYEVENT WORKS???????");
    });

});
```

sockets.js

```
var path = require('path');


module.exports = function (socket) {
   var privateRoom = socket.request.session.passport.user;

    socket.join(privateRoom);


    socket.on('testing', function() {
        console.log('GOT SOME SORT OF RESPONSE!!!');
    });
};
```

Comment: Are you sure `userid` is correct?

Comment: userid @Phix, is the same i assigned it to. so yes

Comment: Can you add the full code please?

Comment: thats basically the full code @Arkerone

Comment: Where you get the socket? socketMVC.on('connection')?

Comment: updated @Arkerone

Comment: Strange, I tested in a local project socketMVC.to doesn't works but io.to works

Comment: You have installed IT right? Your emit for mvc work right? Anyway strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `socketMVC.to` by `socketMVC.io.to`.

Comment: Will check in 12 h. Would that theoretically solve it ?

Comment: @reviewers Please make sure you actually know what you are talking about before recommending deletion / deleting. For all a non domain-expert knows, that could very well be the solution, albeit short. Skipping is always an option.